# curl with multiple proxies working on local server but not on live server

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I have this code that works fine on my local server but doesn't work on a live server.
I'm trying to scrap without getting blocked.

If a proxy gets blocked by the remote server then how come it's working on my local server?

```
function curl_se($set_url,$proxy){

    $ch = curl_init($set_url);
    //set options
    $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,"; 
    $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"; 
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0"; 
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive"; 
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300"; 
    $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"; 
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5"; 
    $header[] = "Pragma: "; //browsers keep this blank.
    //set options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
    echo "</pre>";
    if(curl_errno($ch))
        return false;
    else
        return $result; 
}
```

Looping one proxy on each curl request.

```
$proxy = array(
    "91.83.216.186:8081",
    "190.116.88.11:8080",
    "117.102.9.116:8080",
    "188.165.4.38:3128",
    "187.120.209.10:8080",
    "190.186.50.32:3128",
    "190.108.83.30:8080",
    "190.130.230.149:8080",
    "130.180.18.24:8275",
    "178.33.181.120:8080"
);
```

On the live server I'm getting curl error 7 (CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT)

I'm stuck, it's the same code same URL working fine locally.

**Update:** I figured out that it's something to do with proxy. I tried hundreds of them but none is working on live server getting curl error no 7; tried different website URLs too.
while same proxy and URLs are working on my local server.

Comment: Are you sure your `$set_url` is not point to a location on your localhost ???

Comment: yes, actually It was working fine on live server too for past 2 days. it stopped working this morning. I tested it on 2 different live servers. same error!

Comment: `var_dump(file_get_contents($set_url))` ?? what do you get

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.azlyrics.com/z/zaz.html) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in /srv/disk1/1025371/www/farzoaq.com/output/clone_azlyrics/test_url.php on line 2
bool(false)

Comment: may be my live server ip is blocked by remote server thats why I'm using proxy

Comment: It could be ...... i can see the URL from here .... :)

Comment: yeah, you got me :D, any idea?

Comment: add referrer to your curl option and use new proxies

Comment: (http://www.azlyrics.com/z/zaz.html) it's working on my localhost

Comment: Yes because your ISP address is not yet blocked

Comment: (http://codepad.viper-7.com/xzm8Au) check here your server is running just fine try working proxies like this

Comment: I tried that too, referrer google, new proxies, doesn't work. I'm thinking that may be remote servers can see both real IP and proxy IP?  and they blocked my real server ip? if it goes with my curl requests?

Comment: when you use anonymous proxy then server can't see or block your real ip

Comment: okay, I'll try with new and faster proxies. hope they work

Comment: tried new proxies, failed. then I tried different websites urls using curl-proxies, also failed. one thing I know now is that curl with proxies on live server are not working but they are working on local server.

Comment: @DarkWish was right about trying new proxies, I just tried 8 10 proxies which were working on my local server. anyway about 2 proxies worked out from 100 proxies, got a list of thousand proxies. thanks a lot for pointing to the right direction. :) if you kindly reply this as a answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try working proxies. Check here (codepad.viper-7.com/xzm8Au)  your server is running just fine.   
When you use anonymous proxy, then the remote(destination) server can't see or block your real ip.

Comment: thankyou, it's works with a WORKING Proxy, I just tried 8 10 proxies which were working on my local server. anyway about 2 proxies out of 100 proxies worked on my live server , got a list of thousand proxies. thanks a lot for pointing to the right direction. :) to put it simple way; a proxy working on local server doesn't mean it will also work on live server.